# SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure. Permission denied

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

```
SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Permission denied.
```

Although my test runs perfectly in Firefox and also in IE when running in Debug mode, in IE in Run mode it fails with the error message above. selenium.waitForPageToLoad("20000"); doesn't seem to be a solution.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I was facing the same problem becuase I was using `*iexploreproxy` instead of `*iexplore` when initiating the selenium object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What command is failing with the Permission Denied? It may be when trying to access something that doesn't exist yet. I would recommend using the `waitForCondition` command to ensure the target element is present/visible before attempting to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

I used Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); after the action that requires time to reload parts of the page. It seems to work, but not in all of the cases.

Comment: The problem there is that sometimes 1 second isn't enough, and sometimes it's too much. The former will cause false negatives, and the latter will cause your tests to take longer than they need to.